# TexPad (iOS) to TexWorks (Ubuntu) errors?

Tags: errors, pdftex, texworks

I have installed and wrote a .tex file using texpad, on iOS, using the acmart package. Everything work pretty smoothly. Then, I have pushed the file on my git using working copy.

I have just tried to open this file on Ubuntu, and to generate a pdf. I got the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: File `acmart.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \settopmatter
                 {printacmref=false}
```

and the following console output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./DSE.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `acmart.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
```

My tex file is as follows.

```
\documentclass[manuscript]{acmart}


\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}

\author{Author}
\date{}

\title{\textbf{Title}}


\begin{document}

foo Bar

\end{document}
```

I have checked the encoding with emacs: it is a classic UTF-8 (no BOM). 
Finally, I have many other latex documents that are working perfectly fine on Ubuntu, but that have not been generated on iOS. They also use the acmart package.

Is it possible that creating the file on iOS has created errors? I have also tried to simply copy/past the file and the same error still occurs.

Any hints?

Comment: Looks like you don’t have the acmart class on you Linux System.

Comment: I have it, that is what is puzzling me! As I said, I have other files using acmart class and that are compiling just fine/

Comment: Do you have more than one TeX distribution on your system? What does `kpsewhich acmart.cls` return? The pdflatex you show above is from TeX Live 2017.